# Automatically add an Order column into tablix in Local Report?

Tags: c#, report, reporting, rdlc, localreport

I can populate my own Order column in the DataSource and pass this DataSource to Tablix. But if there is a way to automatically an Order column right in Tablix at design time (such as using some variable or expression), it would be better. Here is what I want:

```
Order      |      Column 1    |    Column 2  
  1
  2
  3
 ...
```

The Order column can be added at design time easily, but how to populate it with ordinal numbers when refreshing report (of course, I don't want to populate it from data source). I want some way to populate it via expression or something like that right in Local Report designer.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 
Put expression `=RowNumber(nothing)` in Order column.

and if you want to show row number differently for group try `=RowNumber("GroupName1")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=RowNumber("Group1")
```

it's not working with me for group numbers what i can do

[image]